# How to add an model-1 relation to the model-2 object that is created by model-3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Model User:

```
has_many :shipments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => 'Friendship', 
                                 :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

Model Friendship:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
```

Model Shipment:

```
belongs_to :user
```

I need User to create an Shipment-object and add (or link somehow) another User from its friendlist to that object.

For example: "User-1" creates object from Shipment-model and in the process (while filling form fields) adds "User-2" from his friendlist (Friendship model object) to that Shipment-model object. So the final Shipment-model object looks somehow like the last example:

```
user.shipment.name
user.shipment.price
user.shipment.friend.name
```

---

**Update from 05.04:**
Made a lots of research and found similar solution with adding another model, now the app looks like this (updates made strong):

Model User:

```
has_many :shipments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => 'Friendship', 
                                 :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
has_many :shipment_users
has_many :shipments, through: :shipment_users
```

Model Friendship:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
```

Model Shipment:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
has_many :shipment_users
has_many :users, through: :shipment_users
```

Model Shipment_User:

```
belongs_to :shipment
belongs_to :user
```

Form for creating Shipment object:

```
<%= form_for(@shipment, html: { multipart: true, role: "form"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :friend_id, User.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Shipment view file:

```
<h4><%= @shipment.user(:id).name %></h4>
<h4><%= @shipment.user.friend(:id).name %></h4>
```

**As a result for now:**
In form Rails founds all existing users and puts them in checkboxes, but ater that nothing happens and in view-file it shows the name of a User who creates the Shipping, but for part "<%= @shipment.user.friend(:id).name %>" I get another error:

```
NoMethodError in ShipmentsController#show
undefined method `friend' for #<User:0x007f1e400e8e08> Did you mean? friends friends=
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! what have you done to try and figure this one out yourself? What have you googled for? What happened when you tried the results? why were you unsatisfied with what you tried? Here at Stack Overflow we expect you to have a go at it yourself before asking for help :) My suggestion would be to have a go with after-create callbacks. Google that and see what you can come up with. If you get an error that you can't get past, come back and tell us what you tried, what the error was and then we can help :)

Comment: For last ~10 hours I have been watching and searching for the solution in different tutorials from youtube to railscast (there I've found the Friendship model/controller examples), but havent found anything to copy the example from. So after all I decided to ask for the solution here.

Comment: Looks like `friend` isn't an association of `shipment`. What would a friend of a shipment mean exactly?

Comment: Great - so tell us what you've tried, so that we don't duplicate that effort! :)

Comment: As I wrote above, I have copied "friendship"-thing from railscast example, after that I had no idea where to look from. Now I have followed Anthony E's reply and added model relation to Shipment (as I wrote below this reply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off `friend` is not an association of shipment. Furthermore, it's not clear which user friend would refer to. If you could clarify this it would help to provide a more specific answer.

Judging by your code, why not just add a simple `friend_id` column to reference the user who is supposed to be a friend for that shipment? In this case your `belongs_to` would  look like:

After you add your friend_id, foreign key. In the Shipment model:

```
belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: Thank you, now I know where to start from. I've added "belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User" " - to Shipment, "friend_id" - to shipment table and next lines to shipment form (Dont know what these means, I copied them from similar case):
<%= form_for(@shipment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :friend_id, Friend.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

But now I get the next error:
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007fc1685ea390>